# Mixins on Grails Domains Classes broken in upgrade to 2.2

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-domain-class

We have a multiple Grails 2.0.3 domain classes that use the @Mixin annotation

like so:

```
@Mixin(PremisesMixin)
class Clinic { 
    Premises premises
    String name
    ....
```

It works really well!

In trying to update to 2.2.2 the mixins don't seem to work. We use the fixtures plugin to bootstrap some data, and in the process of starting up we get errors related to the getters and setters that should injected by the mixins not being present.

I did Find there there are some issues with groovy mixins in more recent versions of grails, but there is a Grails specific replacement http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9901

but changing to

```
@grails.util.Mixin(PremisesMixin)
class Clinic { ...
```

gives other errors.

```
Getter for property 'fax' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

So is there a way to utilize mixins on Grails domain classes in the latest version of grails or do I need to refactor my code to avoid them?

**update**:
the premises mixin which is in src/groovy looks like this:

```
class PremisesMixin implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L

static fields = ['addressLine1', 'addressLine2', 'city', 'county', 'state', 'postalCode', 'plus4', 'phone', 'latitude', 'longitude']

String getAddressLine1() { premises?.addressLine1 }
void setAddressLine1(String addressLine1) { premises?.addressLine1 = addressLine1 }

String getAddressLine2() { premises?.addressLine2 }
void setAddressLine2(String addressLine2) { premises?.addressLine2 = addressLine2 }

String getCity() { premises?.city }
void setCity(String city) { premises?.city = city }

...

String getPhone() { premises?.phone }
void setPhone(String phone) { premises?.phone = phone }

String getFax() { premises?.fax }
void setFax(String fax) { premises?.fax = fax }
    
    ...
    
    // Workaround for open Groovy bug with Mixins https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3612
String toString() {
    this as String
}
}
```

and Premises looks like this:

```
class Premises {
String addressLine1
String addressLine2
String city
String state
    ...
    
String county
String phone
String fax

Double latitude
Double longitude
}
```

Comment: How does `PremisesMixin` look like? I was in the same boat, few months back upgrading to 2.2.0, as you are but Grails @Mixin worked for me.

Comment: edited to include some of the premises mixin content

Comment: I do not see `fax` in static `fields`. And where is `premises`. :)

Comment: good catch on fax not being in static feilds. Added some extra content in question to possible make things more clear.

Comment: Fixing that fax issue did not fix the issue. It still fails to mix in the other getters and setters

Comment: Does the mixin class do anything else then `getters/setters`? if no, then why is Mixin needed for only accessor methods? If I am not wrong, `Premises` is a domain class?

Comment: no, just a way to reuse those getters and setters and mix them into multiple domains that have relationships to premises. for example a doc might have a premises as would a patient ans so on. instead of clinic.premises.addressLine1 it is clinic.addressLine1 and doc.addressLine1 etc. It isn't that I need mixins in this it is just cleaner to use them.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: no, I never did figure out the cause, I suspect it was related to the fixtures plugin, but I ran out of time for experimenting with it.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me in Grails 2.2.2 with the below setup:

```
@grails.util.Mixin(PremisesMixin)
class Clinic {
    String name

    static constraints = {
    }
}

class Premises {
    String fax

    static constraints = {
        fax nullable: true
    }
}

class PremisesMixin {
    //Without this a runtime error is thrown, 
    //like property 'premises' not found in Clinic.
    Premises premises

    void setFax(String fax) {
        premises?.fax = fax
    }
    String getFax() { 
        premises?.fax 
    }
}

//Test Case
def clinic = new Clinic(name: "TestClinic")
clinic.premises = new Premises().save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
clinic.fax = "123456"

clinic.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

Clinic.list().each{assert it.fax == '123456'}
Premises.list().each{assert it.fax == '123456'}
```

The logic for `Mixin` transformation has not been modified for 2.2.x version although I see modifications done on it in `master` branch, but the change is minute(generic class literals used).

**Few Questions:**
 1. How was `premises` accessible in the mixin class? I do not see where it is defined in the Mixin class.
 2. Actually when were you facing the error, `run-app` or during creation of `Clinic`(similar to what is done in test above)?

Comment: Premises is defined on the clinic not on the premises mixin, only getters/setters on the mixin class I may try putting it on the mixin and see if that helps somehow. currently the errors I see are happening at run-app durring the time when the bootstrap initiates a bunch of stuff using the fixtures plugin

Comment: Since you seek Premises to be available for Clinic, Doc, Nurse etc, wouldn't it be useful to add Premises in Mixin? As this is compile time Mixin, premises should be available to all of them. One more thing, I did not use fixtures for my tests, it was plain vanilla code.

Comment: true, I will be giving this a try when the long weekend is over. thanks for the help on this!

Comment: no luck :( `Invalid property 'premises' of bean class [com.Clinic]: Bean property 'premises' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?`

Comment: Mixins in grails domain classes are spotty at best, the grails implementation has a different set of problems than the groovy one. My person opinion is save yourself lots of pain and stay away from mixins on grails domains